# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

После создания моделей проект никак не запускается, вроде бы все сделал правильно.
Думал ошибка как то связана с использование H2 базы данных, но проверил и тут все нормально.

Также думал, что проблема в неправильной реализации NamedEntity, но пока не понял, что именно с ним не так.

Находил похожую проблему, однако ее решение мне не помогло (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou)

**Детальная ошибка**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.pelicanstroy.PelikanStroyApplication.main(PelikanStroyApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)" because "ao" is null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:voting;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <!--Spring-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--H2-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Lombok-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jUnit-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

**BaseEntity**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@MappedSuperclass//аннотация позволяет вынести общие поля в родительских класс не создавая таблицу
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + ":" + id;
    }
}
```

**NamedEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public abstract class NamedEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    protected String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "middleName", nullable = false)
    protected String middleName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    protected String lastName;

    public NamedEntity(Integer id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        super(id);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "[" + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + "]";
     }
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString(callSuper = true, exclude = {"password"})
public class User extends NamedEntity {
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 11)
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 100)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bool default true")
    private boolean enabled = true;
    @Column(name = "registered", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default now()", updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Date registered = new Date();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "role"}, name = "uk_user_roles"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User(User u) {
        this(u.id, u.firstName, u.middleName, u.lastName, u.phone, u.email, u.password, u.enabled, u.registered, u.roles);
    }

    public User(Integer id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String phone, String email, String password, boolean enabled, Date registred, Role role, Role... roles) {
        this(id, firstName, middleName, lastName, phone, email, password, enabled, registred, EnumSet.of(role, roles));
    }

    public User(Integer id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String phone, String email, String password, boolean enabled, Date registered, Set<Role> roles) {
        super(id, firstName, middleName, lastName);
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.registered = registered;
        setRoles(roles);
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roles) ? EnumSet.noneOf(Role.class) : EnumSet.copyOf(roles);
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER,
    ADMIN;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "Role_" + name();
    }
}
```

Comment: версия JDK какая?

Comment: Версия JDK 15..

Comment: это я уже понял. ответ попробуйте и отпишитесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае проблема связана с конструкторами по умолчанию у Ваших сущностей.
Из-за чего у Hibernate не получается создавать прокси-объекты.

В Вашем кейсе я совершенно точно нашел как минимум одну сущность, в которой имеются проблемы с конструктором по умолчанию.

В `User` вы зачем то ограничили уровень доступа для конструктора по умолчанию до `protected`

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
```

Так делать не стоит, потому что Hibernate не сможет до него добраться.

Уровень доступа нужен публичный

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
```

Вам стоит пройтись по всем сущностям и убедиться что у всех сущностей имеется конструктор по умолчанию, и что данный конструктор публичный.
И у `NamedEntity` в том числе.

## Далее

Если это не помогло, то попытайтесь сменить ByteCodeProvider с JavaAssist на ByteBuddy

Для этого

1. Добавляем зависимость в pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.16</version>
</dependency>
```

2. создаём файл `hibernate.properties` в **resources**

Если он был то заменяем там строку (если она есть)

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist
```

на

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=bytebuddy
```

(если не было установлено, то просто проставьте новое значение)

в итоге при запуске видим что все успешно стартовало
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заменил все конструкторы по умолчанию на PUBLIC, не помогло, также сделал конструкторы стандартно, не через Lombok, тоже не помогло, после этого вставил в application.properies данную вами строку, все также не помогло(конструкторы все были PUBLIC)

Comment: @ILYCH, stacktrace остался прежним или изменился?

Comment: @ILYCH можете на гитхаб выложить проект чтобы можно было протестить?

Comment: После смены конструкторов stacktrace остался прежним
На гитхаб сейчас закомичу

Comment: вот ссылка на github - https://github.com/ILYCH404/PelikanStroy

Comment: @ILYCH сейчас освобожусь и посмотрю

Comment: @ILYCH переписал второй пункт пройдите его заново(первый пункт также должен быть выполнен)

Comment: @ILYCH отпишитесь по результату

Comment: проект запустился. Спасибо! Не могли бы вы скинуть статью или вкратце объяснить, в чем была проблема?
(Однако таблицы не создались автоматически, но это уже другая проблема, с ней постараюсь разобраться.)

Comment: @ILYCH для создания таблиц `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` в application.properties

Comment: относительно статей...тут самому разбираться приходилось. а наводка в одном только вопросе на SO была  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70251381/java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-invoke-java-lang-reflect-accessibleobjec

Comment: суть ошибки в целом та же что и была описана в самом тексте ответа - hibernate не смог переварить связку из Lombok'а и наследования и не понимал как создавать прокси

Comment: и мы во-первых сделали публичными конструкторы для того чтобы он смог до них достучаться. во-вторых: добавили альтернативный адаптер для работы с байт-кодом, который уже смог переворить то, что получилось от связки ломбока с наследованием сущностей

Comment: @ILYCH см выше  ответ на комментарий

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139162/discussion-between-ilych-and--).